# Troubleshoot Windows 10 Miracast/Intel Widi connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, miracast

Trying to connect from Windows 10 PC to some screens that supports Miracast/Intel Widi (LG smart, Amazon Fire, ...).

Both sides start the connection process, but sometimes they establish connection correctly, some time PC says connected but screen keeps connecting and finally fails, sometimes error message of type "can not connect", etc.

Where can I find logs or traces about the connection process, to **see more information about the problem** ? The short messages that appears in PC or screen as "Unable to connect" doesn't allows troubleshoot the problem.

That is, even when answers as "try to connect in this way" or "try updating this" are welcome, more important are answers as "in this file you will see the executed connection steps, messages sent/received and more information about the error" or "using this app you will see the logs records and expanded error messages".

Thanks.